# How to set Debug point in JSP file using Intellij

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

I am using IDE Intellij Idea, i can set debug pointer to JAVA files, but i want to set debug pointer in JSP file to evaluate my java code. But its not working, is there any special configuration or setting for this? Please help.

Comment: Make sure JSPs reside in the directory that is configured as the web resource root in IntelliJ IDEA module settings. Refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-web-application.html for the sample configuration.